# Moving Win Thunderbird data to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

After having spent two days trying to use Ubuntu with the Win TB data I gave up.
The TB sub dir content is completely different to Win and adding the Profile.ini file does not help. 
I do not know if this is a Ubuntu problem or if you need to configure TB differently on Ubuntu or what.... I am just lost and wanted so much to start using Ubuntu!
If anyone can help I would be happy!
Curt

Comment: consider using imap vs pop3 ... I have Win TB and Ubuntu TB configured and the data is synchronized perfectly.

Comment: Can't you just make a copy of your Thunderbird profile folder and place this in the location for your Thunderbird profile folder in Ubuntu?

Comment: Concur with @Ballie, that's what I did.

Comment: I have had same profile in shared NTFS partition and later shared ext4 (after XP shut down) partition for 10 years. Copied to laptop & back to desktop. Even when XP version was slightly different than Ubuntu version it still worked. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder and
http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Profiles and
http://www.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/profile

Answer (score 1):

I have to move mails from one google account to another google account and Thunderbird was my favorite tool to use. It can also be used to move your mails under Windows to an account under Ubuntu.

You can export your mails from the Thunderbird you have now to a file ending on `.mbox` (to export: Right click "inbox" (or another folder you want to export), pick import/export, pick export).

To import you can add the `.mbox` to "local files" and synchronize them with the account you made. Drag and drop (into your inbox or other folder you want them copied to) works too.